# Most Likely Source of Metallic Clang When Dropping Clutch on FWD Car

Tags: clutch, front-wheel-drive

When I drop the clutch at 6RPM (or whatever RPM to spin wheels rather than bog down), on cars other than dedicated performance cars, it's usually followed by one or several metallic bangs. It sounds like a metal part snapping in half or like hitting a really bad pothole to the point where it hits the rim.

What is the most likely source for this sound? My "best" guess is that wheel hop is causing some part of the suspension to hit another part of the suspension. Could it be old shocks somehow?

P.S. Not really trying to "troubleshoot" anything here on a specific car - just want to know what I am (probably) breaking.

Comment: What you're describing suggests it's the turbo encabulator. Youtube video about it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xk8_RWO-oIA

Comment: On a more serious note, your question implies this happens to every vehicle with which the clutch is being dumped at 6RPM (Did you mean 6K RPM?). I can tell you this is not the case. If you're hearing a metallic clang when the clutch is dumped, there is an issue which could very well be a motor/transmission mount. We won't even go into the part about whether this should be done to any car or not in the first place.

Comment: I am guessing it happens on most older vehicles that aren't built for driving like an idiot. I know there are ways to get around wheel hop. I am just not around the "launch" crowd enough to intuitively know if it's the mounts like you suggested, something with the shock hitting another part, or the thing people say about axles "twisting" and then somehow decompressing and releasing (I don't really understand this one since they are in the transmission / and then in the knuckle on the other end, but oh well). So, in short, I understand why MTA replied the way he did, but I am still curious.

Comment: There are metal springs on the clutch plate that help isolate the input shaft from the friction disk and provide some shock absorption when the rotational speed of the engine differs from that of the transmission when the clutch is disengaged. Since your engine is at 6kRPM and your car is stopped (therefor transmission at 0RPM), there is certainly a difference in rotational speed! Perhaps it is the sound of these springs being compressed (stretched?) to their limit and hitting a hard stop. Note: This is generally not a nice thing to do them and they eventually respond by breaking.

Comment: @VSO I truly thought you posted a joke question in the spirit of April Fools Day, so I responded in kind. No offense intended. I agree with Paulster2's take on motor mounts. If you leave the hood / bonnet open so you can observe the engine while you dump the clutch, a broken motor mount will allow the engine to rise up unnaturally rather than twist slightly in place.

Comment: @MTA Zero offense taken - I know how much it reads like something a teenager with their first car would post.

Comment: this is the sound of you breaking your car